# How can I access parent field inside a nested relationship in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have to access parent current task_id, because I need to get student solutions of that specific task.

```
SessionsModel::with([
        "attendance", "files", "mentors", "keyPoints", "course", "group",
        "tasks",
        "tasks.solutions" => function ($query) use ($user) {
            if ($user->role === 1) {
                $query->where("student_id", "=", $user->id);
            }
            $query->where('reviewed', '=', 0);
        },
        "tasks.solutions.student",
        "tasks.solutions.student.solutions" => function($q){
            $q->where('tasks.solutions.student.solutions.reviewed-id', 0);
            $q->where('tasks.solutions.student.solutions', '**? PARENT_TASK_ID ?**');
        }
    ])->find($request->get("id"));
```

Comment: what did you try? and did you try passing it inside use in the last `function ($q) use ($task)`?